# How do I get the line number for the appropriate range of a given number? bash

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains a range of integers from least to greatest with one range per line:

```
"1","3"  
"4","7"  
"8","10"  
"11","13"  
"14","20"
```

I need to get the line number for the range appropriate to a given number.

for example:
 If the given number is 2, it should return 1 for line 1 because 2 falls between 1 and 3.

If the given number is 3 it should still return 1 for line 1.

If the given number is 9 it should return 3 for line 3 because 9 falls between 8 and 10.

Comment: Have you attempted anything to solve this? What tools are you limited to using? Does this need to be pure-shell?

Comment: I know that if I use grep -n $num  it will look for the exact match of $num and return it. I was thinking if there is a way to get it to look for the first number that is greater than the given number in the first column. then I can just subtract 1 for the appropriate line number.

num = 5

grep -n  for the first instance of number greater than 5 in column 1. Then subtract 1.

I just don't have any idea as to how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this pretty quick with `awk` as well:

```
sed "s/\"//g" yourfile | awk -F, -v var=$yournumber '$1<=var && $2>=var {print NR}'
```

We're just using `sed` here to get rid of the double-quote string encapsulation. `awk` will then split by a comma and compare `$yournumber` variable to the first and second fields in the text file. If it finds a hit, it will spit out the Record Number (`NR`).

Comment: Alternatively, use `"` instead of `,` as the field separator and compare to `$2`...`$4` instead of `$1`...`$2`; then you don't need the `sed` step.

Answer (score 2):

Pure shell solution assuming your file is formatted exactly as your example:

```
function lineFor {
  local -i target=$1 line=1 a b
  local file=$2
  while IFS=\" read _ a _ b _; do
     if (( a <= target && target <= b )); then
        echo $line
        return 0
     fi
     let line+=1
  done <"$file"
}
```

In action:

```
$  cat -n ranges.txt
      1  "1","3"
      2  "4","7"
      3  "8","10"
      4  "11","13"
      5  "14","20"
$ lineFor 5 ranges.txt
2
```